# Turning list of urls into a navigation pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of sites and sites within those sites. How do I create a navigation tree using ul and li elements given this output?

```
https://hosted.demo.ca
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/bm
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/cmtte
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/dm
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/pm
https://hosted.demo.ca/archive
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/bm
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/dm
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/pm
https://hosted.demo.ca/cdn
https://hosted.demo.ca/cf_test
https://hosted.demo.ca/charity
https://hosted.demo.ca/charity/bod
https://hosted.demo.ca/charity/bod/boarddocs
https://hosted.demo.ca/charity/bod/mtgmaterial
https://hosted.demo.ca/clite
https://hosted.demo.ca/clite/admin
https://hosted.demo.ca/company
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/finance
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/hr
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/hr/b1
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/hr/b1/b2
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/hr/b1/b2/b3
https://hosted.demo.ca/company/mrkting
https://hosted.demo.ca/demo
```

I want to take this list and turn it into something like this:

```
<UL>
  <li>Academic
    <ul>
      <li>BM</li>
      <li>CMTTE</LI>
      <li>DM</li>
      <li>PM</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>ARCHIVE</li>
</UL>
<ul>
  <LI>ASSOCIATIONS
    <ul>
    <li>BM</li>
    <li>DM</LI>
    <li>PM</li>
    </ul>
  </LI>
</ul>
```

Someone suggested I try something like this:

```
  var map = {}; //init the map
  var web = $(xData.responseXML).find("Web");
  for (var i = 0; i < web.length; i++) {
  //we create a index for our links based on the depth of them by `/`
    var m = web[i].attributes['Url'].value.substring(23, web[i].attributes['Url'].value.length).split('/').length; 

    map[m] = map[m] || []; //make sure we leave alone the old values if there is none init with new array
    map[m].push(web[i].attributes['Url'].value); //push new value to node
  }
  console.log(map);
```

But the object it returned took all sites with the same number of "/" and put them in one array. Which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: I updated the original post to show what I tried

Comment: He has posted this "question" multiple times. He's a vampire.

Comment: Your markup for listing is just awfull. Lists inside of lists.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is the same, but the problems in each question is different.

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen, I thought that this was how I was suppose to do it. Isn't that how html menus are structured? I'm open to structuring it another way if that makes it easier.

Comment: @Batman, yes, you could make your list much more simple. I'm creating a solution for you at the moment, so wait a sec. :)

Comment: @Batman, well Gaby already posted hes solution, I don't see need of posting mine anymore, I got more complex approach anyways and hes answer is better than mine.

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen thanks for taking the time to answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
var map = {}; //init the map
  var web = $(xData.responseXML).find("Web")
                .map(function () {
                    return $(this).attr('Url');
                });

  // create map for later use
  for (var i = 0; i < web.length; i++) {
      var item = web[i],
          parts = item.split('/'),
          domain = parts.splice(0, 3).join('/'),
          current;

      if (!map[domain]) map[domain] = {};
      current = map[domain];

     for (var index = 0, length = parts.length; index < length; index++) {
          var part = parts[index];
          if (!current[part]) {
              current[part] = {};
          }
          current = current[part];
      }
  }
  console.log(map);


  // create DOM method
  function traverseMap(obj, element) {
      for (var index in parts) {
          var li = $('<li>', {
              text: item
          }).appendTo(element);

          if (!$.isEmptyObject(obj[item])) {
              var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(li);
              traverseMap(obj[item], ul);
          }
      }
  }

  // invoke the DOM creating function
  traverseMap(map, $('#root'));
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4gJ9T/

---

And with small modifications to hold/show the full url as well (*as links*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4gJ9T/2/

Comment: thanks for the reply. This looks exactly like what I'm trying to accomplish. I've tried to do this with my code but now the object is returning empty. I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere in the implementation. This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/TTVFy/

Comment: @Batman, in your code you need to change `$('data')` to `$(xData.responseXML)` or whatever variable you hold your XML data in ..

Comment: @Batman, additionally you need to pass a `ul` element to the `traverseMap` method and not a `div` because we are adding `li` elements and they can only exist inside a `ul`.

Comment: yea you're right, those changes fixed things right now. Thanks so much for this. I have one more question. The XML data contains an attribute for each <web> element called Title. If I wanted to use the sites Title instead of the parsed value, how could I change this up a bit?

Comment: I made some changes to your solution. I realized that your solution parsed the URL to give each li it's text/title. Since the XML <web> element already had the attribute 'Title' it made that step unnecessary. What I've done is obtained the Title from the XML, added it to the Object and used that for my List Item text. Here's the modification: http://jsfiddle.net/kHwZH/1/  Thanks a lot for your help on this!

Comment: there is an error in the original code.. the `for (var index in parts)` should be `for (var index = 0, length = parts.length; index < length; index++)` for the map creation code

Comment: I'll make the change, but it seems to be working though

Comment: Hmm yea I made the changes but it's not working anymore. It's likely because I've made a few changes and am using the code from the second demo. Take a look at my jsfiddle from my previous post, it shows exactly what I'm using. Perhaps the change isn't necessary?